# Como criar novos TextViews dentro de uma scrollview pelo Java em android studio?

Tags: java, android, xml

Oi, estou com uma duvida para fazer um aplicativo:
Preciso criar um novo TextView dentro de uma ScrollView a cada clique de um botão. Preciso ainda botar atributos ao textview, como posicionamento dele na tela, cor de fundo, e cor do texto. Eu pensei em fazer assim:

`TextView texto = new TextView(this);`

Mas, desse jeito, ele só cria o textview, eu preciso saber como alterar os atributos do textView e como botar na scrollView. Alguem pode me dizer como faço isso?

Answer (score 0):

Sobre setar os atributos que deseja por código:

```
TextView txtView = new TextView(this);
txtView.setTextSize(12);
txtView.setText("hdfas");
txtView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

Comment: obrigado! preciso agora aprender como colocá-lo dentro da scrollview... Mesmo assim, obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

> E preciso saber como alterar os atributos do TextView e como botar na ScrollView

Digamos que tenha uma ScrollView no seu layout, sendo que toda `ScrollView` é um `ViewGroup`, você usaria o método **`addView()`** para colocar seu TextView dentro da ScrollView. Mas sabemos que **ScrollViews só podem conter uma view filha**, então normalmente acabamos com este padrão:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scroll_container"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

em que o LinearLayout *scroll_container* é a única view filha da ScrollView.

Agora usaremos esse LinearLayout (que é um ViewGroup) para servir como host para os TextViews que vamos adicionar.

```
// Primeiro, iniciamos o container
LinearLayout container = findViewById(R.id.scroll_container);

// Criamos o TextView
TextView text = new TextView(this);

// Criamos os parâmetros do layout no qual
// este TextView será inserido
LinearLayout.LayoutParams textParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
textParams.topMargin = dpToPx(16);
textParams.bottomMargin = dpToPx(32);
text.setLayoutParams(textParams);

// Agora brincamos com o TextView
text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
text.setText("https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView");
text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff9800")); // Laranja
text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 16); // 16dp

// Finalmente adicionamos o text ao container
container.addView(text);
```

Aqui está o conversor de DP pra Pixels, coloque-o fora do onCreate:

```
private int dpToPx(int dp) {
    int px = dp;
    try {
        px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    } catch (Exception ignored){}
    return px;
}
```